# Append columns removed from matrix (matlab)?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Through help from users on this site I have come to the following to remove columns from matrix:

```
a = [5 1 4; 2 1 1; 5 2 8];
n = size(a,1)
for i=1:n,  
    [v, i] = min(a(3,:));
    col = a(:, i);
    a(:, i) = [];
end
```

I am looking to combine the col for each of the iterations to one matrix.

Any suggestions?

Comment: changing the for-loop variable inside the loop is not good practice.. What is it you are trying to achieve? there might be a better way to do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I understand the question. Do you want this:

```
a = [5 1 4; 2 1 1; 5 2 8];
n = size(a,1);
result = [];
for i=1:n
    [v, i] = min(a(3,:));
    col = a(:, i);
    result = [result col];
    a(:, i) = [];
end
```

The result would look like:

```
 1     5     4
 1     2     1
 2     5     8
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! The portion I needed was what you have listed as result .. didn't realize that was all that would be needed to add to the matrix at each iteration.

Comment: this is a joke, right? How can this answer be upvoted and accepted. The answer is terrible. It modifies 'i', which is the loop variable. This goes against the most basic programming practice used everywhere. I will never hire anyone who writes code like this.

Comment: @Robert H: I agree that this is not good practice, but it is the exact answer to the question with minimum modifications to the original code ('The portion I needed...'). The purpose of the question was unclear to me, so I did not try to answer something what was probably not asked. I would say the answer has exact the same quality as the question.

Answer (score 3):

obtain the sorting-order for the elements of the third row and use to reshuffle the columns of a:

```
[s idx] = sort(a(3, :);
a_new = a(:, idx);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a few serious problems in your code:

1. You re-assign the loop variable inside the loop. This is horrible practice and can lead to some hard-to-debug, if not undefined behaviour. Always use unique variable names for things that have different meanings.
2. You're using `i` as a variable name. Although perfectly legal in Matlab, it is still considered bad practice, since `i` (and `j`) also denote the imaginary unit. It's like saying `1 = sin(x)`, where you're using `1` not as a number, but as a variable name...Kinda confusing.
3. You're resizing the matrix a on every iteration. This is not the best way to go performancewise -- resizing an array means that matlab has to reserve memory for a new array of different size, copy the contents of the old array to the new one, and delete the old one. All that copying and deleting can take up a lot of time when done in a loop like that, and is wasteful because it isn't needed; you could just do

   ```
    a(:,i) = inf
   ```

   instead of

   ```
    a(:, i) = []
   ```
4. You're re-inventing the wheel. You seem to want to sort the matrix by the elements in its third row. Matlab is perfectly capable of that:

   ```
   b = sortrows(a.',3).'
   ```

   or alternatively

   ```
   [~, inds] = sort(a(3,:);
   b = a(:, inds);
   ```

   Matlab is capable of any relatively basic operation on matrices you can think of, usually also in a variety of ways. And usually, it does a much better job at it than you or I, simply because many of its tools have been developed, improved and debugged over years upon years, by dozens upon dozens of programmers, many of whom much more talented and experienced in a certain area than you or I will ever be.

Comment: I agree with everything, especially (4). But not with (2), about `i`. It is quite rare to use imaginary numbers in some applications, and if you do, you can restrict the usage to small and closed functions. I understand that it is quite subjective and we can discuss it all day long, but still, in my humble opinion, I would not call it a "bad practice".

Comment: @Andrey unless you're doing something with square roots and the root's argument turns negative unintentionally. And would you use 'size' as a variable name? Really, it is better to use 1i or 1j for the imaginary unit, and avoid i and j as variables. How hard is it to type ii or jj?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was trying to portray a much larger problem while making the code simple to get to the point. I will keep these in mind.